# Calling asynchronous code from index.html page

Tags: javascript, html, async-await

Can anyone please help with the following?

In my main html page I use the onLoad method of the DOM like so:

```
<body onLoad="OnLoad()">
```

My OnLoad method is:

```
function OnLoad()
{
     var thing = new Thing();

     thing.GetAsync();

     alert("T");
}
```

Where Thing is:

```
function Thing()
{
}

Thing.prototype.GetAsync = async function ()
{
    var result = await this.AsyncFunc();

    alert(result);
}

Thing.prototype.AsyncFunc = async function ()
{
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve("Text");
        }, 2000);
    });
}
```

When I run this I see "T" immediately and 2 seonds later I see "Text".

Is it possible to await the result of thing.GetAsync() so that "T" will always come after "Text" in the OnLoad method? I gather this may not be possible as it would be attmepting to pause the main browser thread?

Comment: The only change you need to make to fix this is to put `await` in front of `thing.GetAsync();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define onLoad as an async function, and then await thing.GetAsync();

```
async function OnLoad()
{
     var thing = new Thing();

     await thing.GetAsync();

     alert("T");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I tried that. Unfortunately it doesn't work, the page stops loading. I thought to mark OnLoad method as async - function async OnLoad() - but just that in itself is enough to stop the the page from loading. So as even marking OnLoad as async didn't work, I tried TheMisir's method. Yes that gives me the alerts in the desired order, but I am trying to stop the remainder of the code in OnLoad form executing until "Text" has appeared. With this method the code below is still executing immediately

Comment: OK, got it. My fault. Thanks for all your help. I had "function async OnLoad()", should have had it as "async function OnLoad()"

Answer (score 1):

You can add `.then` after async call to wait while Promise is completed. This will not block browser thread. Because the purpose of async calls is making experience smooth rather than blocking UI.

```js
function OnLoad()
{
     var thing = new Thing();
     thing.GetAsync().then(function(result) {
         alert("T");
     });
}
```